# Reference for further reading on the matrix representation of conics?

Tags: matrices, reference-request

I am trying to study conic sections and I found the ["Matrix representation of conic sections"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections) entry on Wikipedia.

Can I get a reference book to go through for further reading?

Comment: The Wikipedia entry itself has a number of notes and references for you.

Comment: I onow but not enough